# QPainter не является наследником QObject?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, наследование, qpainter

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему код

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
isinstance(QtGui.QPainter(), QtCore.QObject)
```

возвращает `False`? Разве `QPainter` не является наследником `QObject`?

Если же он всё же является, то почему я не могу вызвать метод `deleteLater()` класса `QObject`?

Более подробно о том, почему меня это интересует. Вот кусок слота, который завершается ошибкой:

```
QWin32PrintEngine::newPage: EndPage failed (Неверный дескриптор.)
QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted
```

---

```
printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, view)
        if dialog.exec_() != QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            return
        loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
        result = False

        def print_preview(success):
            nonlocal result
            result = success
            loop.quit()

        progressbar = QtWidgets.QProgressDialog(view)
        progressbar.setWindowTitle("Печать")
        progressbar.findChild(QtWidgets.QProgressBar).setTextVisible(False)
        progressbar.setLabelText("Подождите. Идёт отправка файла на печать...")
        progressbar.setRange(0, 0)
        progressbar.show()
        progressbar.canceled.connect(loop.quit)
        page = view.page()
        page.print(printer, print_preview)
        loop.exec_()
        progressbar.close()
        if not result:
            title = "Ошибка"
            text = "Ошибка печати."
            icon = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Critical
            create_messagebox(title, text, icon)
```

Ошибка вылетает при испускании сигнала `cancel` в `progressbar`. Т.е. `QPainter`, находящийся внутри `QPrinter` начинает рисовать, но при нажатии кнопки `cancel`, происходит выход из слота и `QPainter` не может удалиться. Я прочитал на форумах, что для этого нужно вызвать метод `deleteLater()` класса `QObject`, однако, `QPainter` не может вызвать метод из класса `QObject`.

---

РЕШЕНИЕ МОЕЙ ПРОБЛЕМЫ:

Создать класс обёртку `PrinterHandler` и реализовать внутри него метод (слот) `def cancel(self):`, который будет учитывать сценарий работы с принтером `Microsoft XPS Document Writer`.

```
 class PrinterHandler(object):
            def __init__(self):
                self.loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
                self.printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
                self.result = False

            def cancel(self):
                xpsStr = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
                if self.printer.printerName() == xpsStr and not self.result:
                    title = "Внимание"
                    text = "Выбран принтер Microsoft XPS Document Writer. Отменить печать невозможно."
                    icon = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Critical
                    create_messagebox(title, text, icon)
                    return
                self.loop.quit()

        printerHandler = PrinterHandler()
        dialog = QPrintDialog(printerHandler.printer, view)
        if dialog.exec_() != QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            return
        result = False

        def print_preview(success):
            nonlocal result
            result = success
            printerHandler.loop.quit()

        progressbar = QtWidgets.QProgressDialog(view)
        progressbar.setWindowTitle("Печать")
        progressbar.findChild(QtWidgets.QProgressBar).setTextVisible(False)
        progressbar.setLabelText("Подождите. Идёт отправка файла на печать...")
        progressbar.setRange(0, 0)
        progressbar.show()
        progressbar.canceled.connect(printerHandler.cancel)
        page = view.page()
        page.print(printerHandler.printer, print_preview)
        printerHandler.loop.exec_()
        if not result:
            # NEED TO: progressbar закрывается?
            title = "Ошибка"
            text = "Ошибка печати."
            icon = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Critical
            create_messagebox(title, text, icon)
        else:
            printerHandler.result = True
            progressbar.close()
            title = "Печать"
            text = "Файл отправлен на печать."
            icon = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Information
            create_messagebox(title, text, icon)
```

Comment: А зачем вам его удалять таким образом? Вам надо просто создать объект QPainter, передать в него готовое "устройство на котором можно рисовать" (любой из наследников QPaintDevice, в частности QWidget), нарисовать что-нибудь и забыть (когда тело метода завершит свою работу, объект QPainter будет удален автоматически)

Comment: К сожалению, в моём случае при выходе из слота вылетает ошибка. QWin32PrintEngine::newPage: EndPage failed (Неверный дескриптор.) QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted. Сверху дополнил проблему, фрагментом слота, где происходит ошибка.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Попробуйте после `loop.exec_()` добавить `printer.abort()`

Comment: Постараюсь реализовать минимально воспроизводимый пример, однако сейчас я понял, что ошибка возниакет на `ОС Windows`, когда по умоланию стоит принтер для печати в файл (`Microsoft XPS Document Writer`). Тогда, когда файл уже начал создаваться (указано `имя.xps`), то тогда, если нажать на `progressbar'е` `cancel`, то выскочит вышеуказанная ошибка. Может быть кто-то подскажет, как лучше обработать этот сценарий?

Comment: РЕШЕНИЕ МОЕЙ ПРОБЛЕМЫ представил в посте с вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QPainter` выполняет низкоуровневую отрисовку виджетов и других устройств рисования
и не наследуется от `QObject`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что наследуется от `QObject` -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот например QtWidgets.`QWidget` наследуется от `QObject`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, причина в том, что QPainter не нужно метапрограммирование и работа с сигналами, поэтому он не наследует QObject